# How to root an android device / How to get Sqlite Database from Real Unrooted device

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development, i searched many forums for getting Sqlite database file from Android the only option mentioned is if our device is rooted we can access sq lite data.

for that i want to know how to root an android device and also is rooting process is safe or not ??

can any one provide me instruction guide for rooting an android device.Not only for Sqlite purpose but also to change Proxy settings i need **Rooting** so please any one help me...

Kiran

Comment: This would be more suited for android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get SQLite databse file from an Android device that is not rooted, since you have no permission to access data folder.

But you can run your application in an android emulator and you can get your database file from there (this is the easiest and safest method of all).

Rooting process is safe if it is done right, and gives you full access to all features and stuff on your device. It is not safe when you don't know what to do with all that freedom :)

[Here](http://theunlockr.com/2010/10/11/how-to-root-your-android-phone-superoneclick-method/) you can find more about rooting